# Git work-tree on other server

Tags: git, ssh, remote-access, git-remote

I'm trying to deploy a git branch to another server.

I'm using this command line for it: `git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f`.

Since I'm running this line on my git server, it's fine to simply use the relative local path for my $GIT_DIR, but since my target is on another server, I'm not sure how to call it.

I tried `ssh-user@my-domain.com:/user-root-dir/my-repository/my-repository.git`, but it says `fatal: Could not switch to 'ssh-user@my-domain.com:/user-root-dir/my-repository/': No such file or directory` although the directory structure is correct. I double checked for typos.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A worktree must be accessible by `git` using standard filesystem system calls hence it must be mounted as a local FS. Either push your changes over ssh to a remote repo or mount the remote FS using sshfs.

Comment: I see. So with "push to remote server" you mean adding a remote like `git remote add develop ssh-user@my-domain.com:/user-root-dir/my-repository/my-repository.git`? Because when I do so, it tells me `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.

Comment: `/user-root-dir/my-repository/my-repository.git` at the host `my-domain.com` must be a git repo, of course. Bare repo, most certainly.

Comment: It is. I executed `git --bare init my-repository.git` there. That's why I wondered about maybe calling the server wrong with `ssh-user@my-domain.com` for this situation.

Comment: Verify it with `ssh ssh-user@my-domain.com ls /user-root-dir/my-repository/my-repository.git`

Comment: It works fine. I get `branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs` in return. So everything the git repo should have.

Comment: Oh my god, I feel like an idiot now. I executed all the commands out of the repository I wanted to add the remote to, so the `Not a git repository` error didn't mean the remote repository but the one I was trying to add it to (wich wasn't any because I was in my gitlab's root dir, not the project's one). Thank you for your help though!